# Login system with number of tries on python how can i simplify it?

Tags: python, loops, authentication, simplify

I am a Beginner in Python and i made this login system with number of tries. I think it can be simplified Can anyone help?

```
a=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
i=5
if a==1234:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
        
while not a==1234:
    print(f"INVALID PASSWORD ( {i} times left)")
    a=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
    i-=1
    if a==1234:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
    if i==0:
        print("Console has been locked")
        break
```

I tried it to change the number of print("ACCESS GRANTED") but I dont get how to without doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
a = 0
i = 6
while not a==1234:
    a=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
    i-=1
    if a==1234:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
    elif i==0:
        print("Console has been locked")
        break
    else:
        print(f"INVALID PASSWORD ( {i} times left)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
possibility = 5
while True:
    attempt=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
    if attempt==1234:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
        break
    elif possibility > 0:
        possibility -= 1
        print(f"INVALID PASSWORD ( {possibility} times left)")
    else:
        print("Console has been locked")
        break
```

Use more informative names

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loops instead of a while loop.

Here is my answer:

```
max_tries = 5
correct_password = "1234"

for i in range(1, max_tries + 1):
    password = input("Enter the password: ")
    if password == correct_password:
        print("Access granted!")
        break
    else:
        print(f"Wrong password! You have {max_tries - i} more tries.")
        if i == max_tries:
            print("Console has been locked")

print("Closing program...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
i=5    
while True:
    if a==1234:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
        break
    elif i==0:
        print("Console has been locked")
        break
    else:
        print(f"INVALID PASSWORD ( {i} times left)")
        a=int(input("Enter the Password: "))
        i=i-1
```